# How do I remove my Visual Studio 2013 project from a Github repository?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2013

I had it linked to a repository, but that repository was deleted. I want to remove it from the deleted repository and it to a new one.

How do I go about removing it from the already deleted github repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a local (VS project) clone, with a link to a (now deleted) GitHub repo, go to the local repo directory of that VS project, and type:

```
git remote -v
```

Once you see the url of the deleted GitHub repo, remove that reference

```
git remote remove <name>
```